# Перенос строк в блоке с шириной auto css

Tags: css

Как задать стили, что бы текст переносился на новую строчку:

```
<a class="kyl_img" style="float:left;margin:0 10px 10px 0;">
   <img src="7.jpg" alt="" title="">
   <span class="kyl_descr">Например какое-то очень длинное описание тут будет аля улу и так далее ещё пару слов и всё, значит ещё парочку слов и точно всё.</span>
```

Пишу так:

```
.kyl_img{
  border: 1px #A0A0A0 solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.kyl_img img{
  display: block;
}

.kyl_descr{
  background: #A0A0A0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

[image: Вот так получается]

Comment: А что не так-то??

Comment: нужно ширину задать

Comment: @Qwertiy нужно что бы текст переносился на другую строчку. Ширина картинки всегда разная.

Comment: Где? Он и так переносится же.

Comment: Картинка то меньше чем длина текста, белый фон же справа.

Comment: картинке задайте `float:left`

Comment: @mix тогда текст будет справа, нужно что бы он оставался внизу, но переносился, если много текста.

Comment: @Владимир сейчас оформлю ответ

Comment: Для того что бы было динамическое изменения ширины блока под кортику надо подрубать js. Если я все правильно понял

Comment: а такой вариант подойдет? - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3ysmf3h4/

Comment: Отличный вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

может такой вариант подойдет

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  border: 1px #A0A0A0 solid;
  margin: 10px auto; 
}

.block-inner {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.block-inner > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.block-inner-descr {
  background: #A0A0A0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #fff;  
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  border: 1px #A0A0A0 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="block-inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" title="">
    <span class="block-inner-descr">Например какое-то очень длинное описание тут будет аля улу и так далее ещё пару слов и всё, значит ещё парочку слов и точно всё.</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="block-inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" title="">
    <span class="block-inner-descr">Например какое-то очень длинное описание тут будет аля улу и так далее ещё пару слов и всё, значит ещё парочку слов и точно всё.</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="block-inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/550x150" alt="" title="">
    <span class="block-inner-descr">Например какое-то очень длинное описание тут будет аля улу и так далее ещё пару слов и всё, значит ещё парочку слов и точно всё.</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="block-inner">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x150" alt="" title="">
    <span class="block-inner-descr">Например какое-то очень длинное описание тут будет аля улу и так далее ещё пару слов и всё, значит ещё парочку слов и точно всё.</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это кроссбраузерный код?

Comment: @Владимир да, по IE8 включительно

Answer (score 1):

Решение с помощью jquery:

```
$(".kyl_img img").each(function(){
    var w_img = $(this).width();
    $(this).parent().css("width", w_img + "px");
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Обеим блокам нужно задать `float` и `width`.

Мое решение данной задачи(CSS 3):

```css
.kyl_img {
  border: 1px #A0A0A0 solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.kyl_img img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%
  display: block;
}

.kyl_descr {
  float: left;
  background: #A0A0A0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 20px); /* 20px -  отступы: 10 - слева, 10 - справа */
}
```

```html
<a class="kyl_img" href="#">
  <img src="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/Voodoo/Google.png" alt="" title="">
  <span class="kyl_descr">Например какое-то очень длинное описание тут будет аля улу и так далее ещё пару слов и всё, значит ещё парочку слов и точно всё.</span>
</a>
```

P.S. С шириной можно поиграть или выставить статичную ширину.

Comment: А разве ему не под картинкой надо что бы изменялся блок с текстом?

Comment: В таком случае css-ом не решишь проблему.

Comment: Спасибо за старание, но мне нужно именно css решение, что бы текст был внизу, а не сбоку. Сделал при помощи jquery.